# Updating the repository isn't working

Tags: apt, repository

When I run `sudo apt-get update` get this output:

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Also Ubuntu software Center is not opening.

Comment: Is "E:type" really all you see?

Comment: @fkraiem No sorry, the rest disapeared I see                            sudo apt-get update
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: @Sydney try `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` and after that `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have saved an HTML page as a source list. The instructions for PlayOnLinux on trusty, [from the website](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html#pres_item6), are:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

To check that there's no problems with the internet connection, before executing the above commands, you can do:

```
wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O -
```

This should give:

```
deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ trusty main
```

as the output.

Comment: YOU beat me too it!!! :(  I am not happy with you!

Comment: if that doen't work than she needs to remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` file first, and that would take care of it.

Comment: @Andrew sorry about that. :)

Comment: Thank you both! Do you guys happen to know how to fix my software center? I really know nothing about ubuntu/linux. ): My windows crashed so to save me some money my brother put this on my laptop and im having a lot of trouble with it!

Comment: @Sydney if the playonlinux problem is solved, you can (should) post a new question about the Software Centre issue.

Comment: @Sydney don't forget to click on the check mark by his answer.