# Apt-get update comes up with "Sources list couldn't be read

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I tried to update the packages through the terminal and I get this error every time, david@david-Satellite-C55-B:~$ apt-get update
E: Type '

Now the Software center doesn't work and I have a warning sign on the task bar next to the wifi symbol. Please help!

Comment: Please add the full error message..

Answer (score 1):

You need to run apt-get as root or sudo.

Example:

```
sudo apt-get update
*password*
```

Also run any other apt-get commands as root or sudo.

Example:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you are quick enough after the first command, you do not need to give your password again.

Comment: I get this when I do. Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: @DavidWingard: Looks like your question is a duplicate, please find your solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525819/updating-the-repository-isnt-working